# Transform invalid nested json to valid one and change to list

Tags: python, json, simplejson

Under this link :
http://dev1.gecoloco.com/rte/done_json.php 
I have a json-like object, that I'm operating on. I cannot load it with simplejson, because it is wrongly formatted. And thus this code fails :

```
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("dev1.gecoloco.com")
conn.request("GET", "/rte/done_json.php")
r = conn.getresponse()
data = r.read()
logging.debug(data)
json = simplejson.loads(data)
```

As a result I'd like to get a list of dictionaries.
So first question is how to load it as proper json? Read as string and then replace quotes or something different ?
Second question is how to transform the properly formatted json to a list of dictionaries ? (Do I even need json to do this easily?) ?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: In addition to `ast.literal_eval`, you could also do `simplejson.loads(data.replace("'", '"')`. This works fine for me using the `json` module which is supposed to be the same. You should probably complain to whoever is in charge of that sight. JSON is pretty hard to mess up. I'm sure they'd be really embarrassed and will fix it immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nice thing about JSON is that it's so, so very close to Python literal syntax. Use [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to parse it.